# Which of the prophets and messengers are known to have drunk alcohol (if any)?

Tags: history, prophets, alcohol, messengers

Drinking alcohol is [haram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_dietary_laws):

> **They ask you about wine and gambling. Say, "In them is great sin and [yet, some] benefit for people. But their sin is greater than their benefit."** And they ask you what they should spend. Say, "The excess [beyond needs]." Thus Allah makes clear to you the verses [of revelation] that you might give thought. -- [Qur'an 2:219](https://quran.com/2:219)
>
> O you who have believed, **do not approach prayer while you are intoxicated** until you know what you are saying or in a state of janabah, except those passing through [a place of prayer], until you have washed [your whole body]. And if you are ill or on a journey or one of you comes from the place of relieving himself or you have contacted women and find no water, then seek clean earth and wipe over your faces and your hands [with it]. Indeed, Allah is ever Pardoning and Forgiving. -- [Qur'an 4:43](https://quran.com/4:43)
>
> **O you who have believed, indeed, intoxicants, gambling, [sacrificing on] stone alters [to other than Allah], and divining arrows are but defilement from the work of Satan, so avoid it that you may be successful.** -- [Qur'an 5:90](https://quran.com/5:90)

I'm not entirely sure about the timeline in which these ayah were revealed, but as I understand, they were revealed to Muhammad, so would not have been accessible to the other [prophets and messengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophets_and_messengers_in_Islam) who predate Muhammad.  As such, it seems plausible that they drank alcohol.  It may be they didn't; they're prophets and messengers after all.  (Or maybe they were declared haram in a prior [holy book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_holy_books).)

*Question*: Which of the prophets and messengers are known to have drunk alcohol (if any)?

Comment: For the chronology you may take a look at this post http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28313/was-alcohol-permitted-very-long-before

Comment: As far as i can tell there's no quote about that in Quran! I have no clue whether it is in the sunnah, but I know that at least sunni scholars say that a part of the virtue of Prophets is that they don't commit a major sin. Assuming this is true none of them would be known for drinking alcohol.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I'm not sure about this, but I think I have read that some scholars believe the accounts of Isa having turned water to wine and drinking it to be true. The idea is that different prophets have different sets of laws, and it might have been allowed for Isa.

Answer (score 1):

Which of the prophets and prophets of alcohol is known (if any)?
It is narrated in a hadith from Imam Sadiq (as) that he said: God never sent a prophet except by forbidding alcohol and acknowledging God for bad things.
God did not send any prophet except that the prohibition of wine was part of the mission plan and wine was forbidden from the beginning. In the same vein, it has been narrated from the Prophet of Islam, peace be upon him and his family, and Imam Reza, peace be upon him, and it indicates that the consumption of alcohol has been forbidden since the time of Adam, peace be upon him, and has not been allowed by any prophet Is .

Ref: https://trandnews.ir/%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86-%DA%A9%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%A2%D9%85%D8%AF-%D9%88/