# Getting high and praying by accident?

Tags: salat

Let's say you had a friend that smoked and you didn't but he smoked w you in a car or room outdoors whatever's the case be this is just an example and you got high from the smell of there smoke can you stil pray? Even when your high w no intentions of wanting to be under the influence

Comment: Praying is an ordered act of worship, which is ordered at specific times, of course you must pray!

Comment: even while being under the influence of drugs??

Comment: The question is when should you pray, or whether it is allowed to delay prayer in such a situation not whether you should pray or not!

Comment: The question is it permissible to pray under the influence of drugs with no intentions of wanting to be on drugs

Comment: My first draft would be to say you should wait until you can think clearly based on http://legacy.quran.com/4/43 also see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28313/was-alcohol-permitted-long-ago-before-mohammad-was-born/29160#29160