# Are there rulings, apart from alcohol consumption, whose chronology may be found in the Qur'an?

Tags: quran, fiqh, tafseer, history, uloom-al-quran

In the Qur'an we find the chronology of the ruling on alcohol see for example in my answer on [Was alcohol permitted long ago, before Mohammad was born?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28313/was-alcohol-permitted-long-ago-before-mohammad-was-born): Alcohol allowed, alcohol declared as bad, consummation of alcohol was not allowed if one wants to pray and finally alcohol was prohibited totally.

And we learn that many verses have been abrogated:
[Which Qur'an verses are obsolete?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38244/which-quran-verses-are-obsolete) and replaced.

My question is are there any other rulings on which the Qur'an still shows a chronology of the rulings except for those on alcohol and its consummation?
To give the question more focus I'd add that there's even a change of the possible punishment or permissibility (haram becomes halal or otherwise).

If so examples with quotations of the relevant verses would be welcome!

Comment: I don't fully understand this question. The chronology of the prohibition of wine is not present in the Quran itself, it is in tradition. Next, I suppose that there are probably several such examples where a verse is abrogated or Takhsis is made. Hadd of Zina, Wasiyah, Jihad, some laws of Marriage etc. A comprehensive answer would probably be too broad.

Comment: @UmH My intention is that there are still clear passages in the Qur'an showing that the ruling was otherwise before. I've adapted my post a bit more. If this is still too broad do you have any suggestion to focus it more?

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means an exhaustive list, but some major instances that come to mind:

The Hadd of fornication originally was as in [4:15-16](https://legacy.quran.com/4/15-16) and was abrogated by [24:2](https://legacy.quran.com/24/2). In the earlier verse there is a hint of future abrogation:

> أو يجعل الله لهن سبيلا
>
> ... or Allah ordains for them [another] way.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:15](http://quran.com/4/15)</sup>

Fighting was originally forbidden and then prescribed, there is a clear statement on an abrogation:

> قيل لهم كفوا أيديكم وأقيموا الصلاة وآتوا الزكاة فلما كتب عليهم القتال
>
> ... were told, "Restrain your hands [from fighting] and establish prayer and give zakah"? But then when fighting was ordained for them ...
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:77](http://quran.com/4/77)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I know one hadeeth:

> **I said to Ibn 'Abbas:** *'Can a person, who killed a believer intentionally, repent?'*
>   **He said:** *'No.'*
>   **I recited the Verse from Al-Furqan to him:**
>   *'And those who invoke not any other ilah (god) along with Allah, or kill such person as Allah has forbidden, except by right,'*
>   **He said:** *'This Verse was revealed in Makkah and was abrogated by a Verse that was revealed in Al-Madinah: 'And whoever kills a believer
>   intentionally, his recompense is Hell.'*
>
> Grade : Sahih (Darussalam)
>   Reference : Sunan an-Nasa'i 4001
>   In-book reference : Book 37, Hadith 36
>   English translation : Vol. 5, Book 37, Hadith 4006

The ayah that "claimed" as abrogated is: https://quran.com/25/68-70
Hadeeth only mentions 68th ayah, but ayah 70th shows a way out (chapter 25) so I included all.

The ayah which "abrogates" above: https://quran.com/4/93

**Finally**, Ibn Kathir on his "Quran Tafsir" has some views on the subject definitely worthy of mention:

> Ibn 'Abbas held the view that the repentance of one who intentionally
>   murders a believer, will not be accepted. Al-Bukhari recorded that Ibn
>   Jubayr said, "The people of knowledge of Al-Kufah differed on this
>   subject, I traveled to Ibn 'Abbas to ask him about it. He said, 'This
>   Ayah,
>
> (And whoever kills a believer intentionally, his recompense is Hell)
>
> was the last revealed on this subject and nothing abrogated it. Muslim
>   and An-Nasa'i also recorded it. However, the majority of scholars of
>   the earlier and later generations said that the killer's repentance
>   can be accepted. If he repents, and goes back to Allah humbly,
>   submissively, and performing righteous deeds, then Allah will change
>   his evil deeds into good deeds and compensate the deceased for his
>   loss by rewarding him for his suffering.
>   *http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=617*

**Disclaimer**: these all public information, I do not deny or support any of views here. I gave references and links, as always do you own research and verification on the subject.

Comment: If I comprehend the question correctly, it is asking for matters where 'this abrogates this' is clearn in the Kuran itself, rather than in Hadith.

Comment: Are you *sure* about this "clearness" ?

Comment: No I am not :-)