# What is the meaning of “best of people’s property is not taken for zakat” Hadith

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, zakat, dawah

Asalamu alaikum, please help me understand what the RasulAllah SAW meant by best property. JazakAllahu Khayran in advance.

> When the Prophet (ﷺ) sent Mu`adh to Yemen, he said to him, "You are going to a nation from the people of the Scripture, so let the first thing to which you will invite them, be the Tauhid of Allah. If they learn that, tell them that Allah has enjoined on them, five prayers to be offered in one day and one night. And if they pray, tell them that Allah has enjoined on them Zakat of their properties and it is to be taken from the rich among them and given to the poor. And if they agree to that, then take from them Zakat but avoid **the best property of the people**."
> ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7372))

Answer (score 1):

This hadith is a lesson on good and long-sighted way for da'awa.

Mu'ad in this hadith was sent to do da'wa (invite non-Muslims to Islam) in Yemen where a notable part of the population was from ahl al-Kitab, al-'Ayny  بدر الدين العيني in his 'Umdat al-Qary عمدة القاري explained how the Jewish came to Yemen and where later mixed by Christian, but after the failure of Abraha to demolish al-Ka'aba only settled in Najran between Mekka and Yemen, while the Jewish settled there in Yemen. So according his explanation these ahl al-Kitab were Jewish.
the prophet () gave Mu'ad a good advice in several steps:

1. Invite them to Tawheed.
2. (only) after they have accepted Tawheed (only reciting the two shahadah is not enough), tell them about Allahs orders starting with the five daily prayers.
3. (only) after they have accepted praying (they must perform the prayer in order to achieve this step), tell them Allah ordered Zakat on their property.
   But do not take from their property the best of it (at this stage).

At this point I must do a break because this is the content of this hadith.

Just for your information according Badr ad-Deen al-'Ayny (again) in his book:

> **the best property of the people**

it **was referring to their** sheep more exactly to the **ewe (female sheep) which can offer much of milk**. You could imagine that taking these for zakat would mean for them a financial loss, which may lead to a new hostility and refusal of the rules of Islam (at this stage).

Another hadith tell us what happened after Thaqif accepted Islam:

> Wahb said: I asked Jabir about the condition of Thaqif when they took the oath of allegiance. He said: They stipulated to the Prophet (ﷺ) that there would be no sadaqah (i.e. zakat) on them nor Jihad (striving in the way of Allah). He then heard the Prophet (ﷺ) say: Later on they will give sadaqah (zakat) and will strive in the way of Allah when they embrace Islam.
> ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3025) and also Musnad Ahmad)

Therefore 'Umar ibn 'abd al-'Aziz was reported saying (with full chain) -see for example [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&flag=1&bk_no=131&ID=1259) (in Arabic) in abi Nu'ayms Hilyat al-Awliyaa' حلية الأولياء وطبقات الأصفياء-:
 <sup>In the following I'm translating form Arabic language, as these translations are of my own take them carefully!</sup>

> حدثنا سليمان بن أحمد ، ثنا أحمد بن يحيى ثعلب النحوي ، ثنا الزبير بن بكار ، ثنا محمد بن مسلمة ، عن هشام بن عبد الله بن عكرمة قال : قال عمر بن عبد العزيز : ما طاوعني الناس على ما أردت من الحق حتى بسطت لهم من الدنيا شيئا .
> People did not obey me to what I wanted from the truth until I spread something for them from the world.

Another example: [Ibn 'abdi Rabbih al-Andalussi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Abd_Rabbih) ابن عبد ربه quoted in his al-'Aqd al-Fareed العقد الفريد -see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/23789/43#p6) in Arabic- (a similar statement should be quoted in Tareekh Dimashq تاريخ دمشق of ibn 'Assakir ابن عساكر) another statement of 'Umar ibn 'abd al-'Aziz:

> وقال عبد الملك بن عمر بن عبد العزيز لأبيه عمر: يا أبت، مالك لا تنفذ في الأمور، فو الله لا أبالي في الحق لو غلت بي وبك القدور.
> قال له عمر: لا تعجل يا بني، فإن الله تعالى ذم الخمر في القرآن مرتين وحرمها في الثالثة، وأنا أخاف أن أحمل الناس على الحق جملة فيدفعوه وتكون فتنة.
> 'Abd al-Malik ibn Omar ibn 'abd al-'Aziz said to his father, 'Umar: O Father, Why don't you carry out the rules/affairs, by Allah I do not care about the truth if you boost me and your pots.
> 'Umar said to him: Do not hurry, my son, for Allah the Almighty condemned alcohol twice in the Qur’an and forbade it in the third.

So offering people who are willing to accept Islam a bit of "ease" by any means is a good way to help them accept Islam more easily. Especially in cases where a bit of leniency is acceptable.

In the given case: one may chose other sheep instead of such ewe's.

Once this is accepted these people would reach the next step in their acceptance of Islam:

4. they will accept Islam without any conditions or exceptions.

Note that Allah did the same with many rules Muslims today know by the final order/ruling see for example:

- [Was alcohol permitted long ago, before Mohammad was born?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28313/was-alcohol-permitted-long-ago-before-mohammad-was-born)
- [Are there rulings, apart from alcohol consumption, whose chronology may be found in the Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50126/are-there-rulings-apart-from-alcohol-consumption-whose-chronology-may-be-found)

**Some corresponding fiqh rules**

Further from a fiqh perspective:
Imam al-Qurafy القرافيsaid in his al-Furooq كتاب الفروق -see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2215/160) in Arabic-:

> يشترط في خطاب التكليف علم المكلف وقدرته على ذلك الفعل
> The order assignment requires knowledge of the Mukallaf and his ability to do that

This means a person who is not able to fulfill orders -for reasonable reasons- is exempt from doing them (until he/she would be able to). Such kind of person therefore is regarded as not being addressed by the corresponding orders of the shari'a unless he/she would be able to fulfill them (again).

Al-Qurafy further added a rule -see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2215/684) in Arabic-:

> والقاعدة أن المتعذر يسقط اعتباره والممكن يستصحب فيه التكليف
> The rule is that the impossible is forfeited and the possible is accompanied by the assignment or order

Comment: Understood. So as a lesson, we shouldn’t give away our best properties as zakat in which it would be a financial loss for us?

Comment: @Mehnaaz no that is wrong you totally misinterpreted the answer. You are a Muslim not a person who is invited to Islam. Of course you must pay Zakat and offer from among the best of your property. Similar to those former Jews.