# Alcohol has positive aspects. Putting aside aspect of sin, will the singer be rewarded for the fact that he is entertaining and making happy millions?

Tags: fiqh, sunnah, reward, singing, pornography

Quran says: Alcohol has some positive things but the negative things outweigh the positive things. In a similar fashion. Will they be rewarded for the positive aspects of their sin?  Singing is a major sin that has all those negative effects like increasing hypocrisy. But the singer also produces epic amount of pleasure, entertainment and happiness to millions of people through his voice. My question is: Will he be rewarded like the reward of doing a good deed for the fact that he is entertaining and making happy millions of people through his voice? What about the porn actor?

Comment: Why should a sin be rewarded?

Comment: The verse of Qur'an you refer to is considered as abrogated as part of the chronology of declaring alcohol haram. See for example in https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/29160/13438

Comment: Your question is incoherent. The Quran says that wine has *benefit* for the people although the sin outweighs any benefit. There is no link between that and good deed or reward.

Comment: We can assume Abu Sufyan also made pagans happy when he decided to fight the Prophet of Islam! So would he be rewarded for making pagans happy? Poets also made them happy when they sung in praise of idols? Do they get the reward? Victims of torture may also be an object of pleasure for their sadistic torturers? Do the they get reward for that? What kind of logic is that?

Answer (score 2):

Answer: certainly not.

When some act is sinful then Allah the Almighty in His deep knowledge and wisdom has declared anything related to it as sinful. The best example actually is Zina where even coming close to it is blamed. As for alcohol or riba a whole lot of people who are directly involved with it are blamed and also some people who are indirectly involved in the consummation.

Singing is considered a sin by many if not most scholars. Listening to a singer is also a sin for those scholars.

The same is the case for porn as Zina is haram and even watching or looking at the 'awrah of a non-mehram person (not necessarily the intimate parts) is haram (Zina of the eyes).

So in both cases we are talking about a bad deed which is haram and would be registered as such for all the performer, the listener or the person who watches it.